# How to scroll 2 content at the same time in flutter?

Tags: flutter, gridview, scroll

I want to scroll content(which is above gridview) and gridview same time but didn't figure out how to do that.

Here is my code:

```
body: Padding(
    padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(16, 48, 16, 16),
    child: Column(
    children: <Widget>[
      Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
        children: <Widget>[
          Container(
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(8),
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12),
                color: secondaryColor
            ),
            child: Icon(Icons.person, color: primaryColor,),
          ),
          Text(
            'HOME',
            style: GoogleFonts.montserrat(
                color: primaryColor,
                fontSize: 16,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold
            ),
          ),
          Container(
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(8),
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12),
                color: secondaryColor
            ),
            child: Icon(Icons.search, color: primaryColor,),
          ),
        ],
      ),
      SizedBox(height: 40,),
      ClipRRect(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12),
        child: Container(
          color: secondaryColor,
          height: 350,
        ),
      ),
      SizedBox(height: 20,),
      Align(
        alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
        child: Text(
          'Weekly Highlights',
          style: GoogleFonts.montserrat(
              color: Colors.white,
              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
              fontSize: 18
          ),
        ),
      ),
      Flexible(
        child: GridView.count(
          crossAxisCount: 2,
          children: List.generate(50, (index) => Container(child: Card(child: Text(index.toString()),),)),
        ),
      )
    ],
  ),
),
```

Comment: Do you mean you want to scroll the whole page ie. all the widgets including your Gridview?

Comment: exactly, I want to scroll whole page including gridview

Comment: Wrap your column with SingleChildScrollView and you can use NonScrollableScrollPhysics in GridView, that should help.